# Where is documentation for openid1_claimed_id?

Tags: django, openid

OpenID, using delegation, seems to be returning `openid1_claimed_id` instead of `openid.claimed_id`

That looks like “an OpenID 1 version of claimed_id” but I can't find it documented anywhere.

Miscellaneous details:

- OpenID URL: http://www.zellyn.com/
- Delegated to: http://zellyn.myopenid.com/
- Using [django-socialregistration](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Another query parameter that gets added to the return_to for
# OpenID 1; if the user's session state is lost, use this claimed
# identifier to do discovery when verifying the response.
openid1_return_to_identifier_name = 'openid1_claimed_id'
```

-- from the [python-openid](http://github.com/openid/python-openid/blob/master/openid/consumer/consumer.py#L558) source.